# 'and' keyword help in google drive api's "try it yourself"

Tags: google-drive-api

Is your sandbox (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) not working properly or am I doing this wrong? 
Here's the parameters I'm putting in for q--

'[folderid]' in parents and name contains '[document name]'

^^ folderId and document name are of course replaced with actual things (no brackets) in my search.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you read my answer?

Comment: yes sorry I didn't have internet for a while! works when you just make the call yourself -- but not on the sandbox. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is the "**name**" keyword, not "**and**".

For some reason, in v2, the query textfield for *Try It Yourself* does not accept "**name**" keyword. It always returns error `"The value of the parameter 'q' is invalid."` 
But, I noticed that if you changed 'name' with 'fullText', like:

```
'folderid' in parents and fullText contains 'Android'
```

then it works. The query is accepted.

However, this seems to have been fixed in Drive v3. In v3,"**name**" is accepted query keyword. Thus,

```
'folderid' in parents and name contains 'Android'
```

works like a charm.